# Jquery .change can't retrieve inserted checkbox values

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I have a serious problem in my script when I want to add a new checkbox input through ajax call. The problem is that i can't retrieve the value of this checkbox after it's inserted. When i change selection1 and selection2 and selection 3 and options. The alert must show the values of the 4 fields on every field change.

I give an example here in jsfiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/pm4t91ab/39/

Script Code :

```
<script>
$(function() {
  $(".ch").change(function() {
    // Récupérer les données du formulaire
    var select1 = $("select#id1").val();
    var select2 = $("select#id2").val();
    var country = $("select#country").val();
        var options = "";
    var op = "<td>Options :</td>" +
      "<br />" +
      "<td>" +
      "<div>" +
      "<label>" +
      "<input type='checkbox' class='ch' id='option1' name='options' class='ch' value='1'>Option1</label>" +
      "</div>" +
      "<div>" +
      "<label>" +
      "<input type='checkbox' id='option2' name='options' class='ch' value='2'>Option2</label>" +
      "</div>" +
      "</td>";

    if (country != "") {
      $('#options_insert').html(op);
    }

    // Bind the elements dynamically created here and get the selected items
    $(document).on('click', 'input[name="options"]', function() {
      var options = $("input[name=options]:checked").map(function() { return this.value;}).get().join(",");
    });


    alert("select1=" + select1 + " select2=" + select2 + " Country=" + country + " options=" + options);

  });

});
</script>
```

Html Code :

```
<table>

  <tr>
    <td>
      Selection 1 :
    </td>
    <td>
      <select name="select1" class="ch" id="id1">
        <option value="">Nothing</option>
        <option value="val1">val1</option>
        <option value="val2">val2</option>
        <option value="val3">val3</option>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>
      Selection 2 :
    </td>
    <td>
      <select name="select2" class="ch" id="id2">
        <option value="">Nothing</option>
        <option value="val1">sel1</option>
        <option value="val2">sel2</option>
        <option value="val3">sel3</option>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>
      Selection 3 :
    </td>
    <td>
      <select name="select" class="ch" id="country">
        <option value="">Nothing</option>
        <option value="val1">Maroc</option>
        <option value="val2">USA</option>
        <option value="val3">Egypt</option>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="options_insert">

  </tr>
</table>
```

any help will be very apreciated

Comment: I see no checkboxes in your HTML; only selects (dropdowns).  Are you looking to add a listener to new dropdowns?

Comment: Please visit my jsfiddle and change the value of the 3rd select. Or in my script the var op contain the checkbox code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an updated version of your code. It separates the alert values event handling (when a form value changes) from the show options event handling (when the country value changes).

```js
$(document).on('change', "select#country", function() {
  var $optionsElement = $('#options_insert');
  var $selectCountry = $("select#country").val();

  if ($selectCountry === '') {
    $optionsElement.html("");
  } else {
    $optionsElement.html("<td>Options :</td>" +
      "<br />" +
      "<td>" +
      "<div>" +
      "<label>" +
      "<input type='checkbox' class='ch' id='option1' name='options' class='ch' value='1'>Option1</label>" +
      "</div>" +
      "<div>" +
      "<label>" +
      "<input type='checkbox' id='option2' name='options' class='ch' value='2'>Option2</label>" +
      "</div>" +
      "</td>");
  }
});

$(document).on('change', '.ch', function() {
  var $select1 = $("select#id1").val();
  var $select2 = $("select#id2").val();
  var $selectCountry = $("select#country").val();
  var $options = $("input[name=options]:checked").map(function() {
    return this.value;
  }).get();

  alert("select1=" + $select1 + " select2=" + $select2 + " Country=" + $selectCountry + " options=" + $options.join(","));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>

  <tr>
    <td>
      Selection 1 :
    </td>
    <td>
      <select name="select1" class="ch" id="id1">
        <option value="">Nothing</option>
        <option value="val1">val1</option>
        <option value="val2">val2</option>
        <option value="val3">val3</option>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>
      Selection 2 :
    </td>
    <td>
      <select name="select2" class="ch" id="id2">
        <option value="">Nothing</option>
        <option value="val1">sel1</option>
        <option value="val2">sel2</option>
        <option value="val3">sel3</option>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>
      Selection 3 :
    </td>
    <td>
      <select name="select" class="ch" id="country">
        <option value="">Nothing</option>
        <option value="val1">Maroc</option>
        <option value="val2">USA</option>
        <option value="val3">Egypt</option>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="options_insert"></tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, here's the problem. You are adding additional elements to the DOM (the checkboxes) and when this happens you typically need to add event listeners to them.  However, instead you can just change this line:

```
$(".ch").change(function() {
```

...to this...

```
$("table").on('change', '.ch', function() {
```

And that should do the trick. [Here's more information.](http://www.javascripter.net/faq/eventbubbling.htm)

Comment: Yes men i implement it here : https://jsfiddle.net/pm4t91ab/47/ ans it works. But there is a problem. i can't choose option1 and option2 at the same time. The checkbox don't still checked after click.

Comment: That's because you are actually replacing the checkbox on checkbox change.  Instead of appending the checkboxes, I suggest show/hide instead.

Answer (score 0):

In JQuery you need to bind the event of the dynamically added elements using "on"

for example,

```
 $(function() {
      $(".ch").change(function() {
        // Récupérer les données du formulaire
        var country = $("select#country").val();

        var op = "<td>Options :</td>" +
          "<br />" +
          "<td>" +
          "<div>" +
          "<label>" +
          "<input type='checkbox' class='ch' id='option1' name='options' class='ch' value='1'>Option1</label>" +
          "</div>" +
          "<div>" +
          "<label>" +
          "<input type='checkbox' id='option2' name='options' class='ch' value='2'>Option2</label>" +
          "</div>" +
          "</td>";

        if (country != "") {
              $('#options_insert').html(op);
        }
        // Since this is in the change event of the select
        // It will never have item selected
        var options = $("input[name=options]:checked").map(function() {
          return this.value;
        }).get().join(",");

        alert("Country=" + country + " options=" + options);

      });

        // Bind the elements dynamically created here and get the selected items
        $(document).on('click', 'input[name="options"]',function(){
            var options = $("input[name=options]:checked").map(function() {
              return this.value;}).get().join(",");

              alert(options);
        });
    });
```

Comment: Not what i want. look at this jsfiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/pm4t91ab/39/. When i change selection1 and selection2 and selection 3 and options. The alert must show the values of the 4 fields on every field change

Answer (score 0):

It does not work because you try to retrieve values of checked inputs and checkboxes you inserting are unchecked by default. Besides that, it will work only just after insert. If you need to get values of that checkboxes after selecting them you have to create new event e.g

```
$('table').on('click','input[type="checkbox"]',function(){
    var options = $('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').map(function() {
        return this.value;}).get().join(",");
});
```

Comment: Not what i want. look at this jsfiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/pm4t91ab/39/. When i change selection1 and selection2 and selection 3 and options. The alert must show the values of the 4 fields on every field change